# Add Indent Lines similar to those in Sublime

Tags: visual-studio-code

How do I add indent lines to my vscode? `editor.renderIndentGuides: true` doesn't work properly - at least on Mac. I think it used to be okay until some of the recent updates...

Here is an example image from Sublime. All indent lines are there and are displayed properly:
[SUBLIME Proper version of Indent lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bPqF.png)

and here a buggy version from vscode.
[VSCODE Buggy and broken indent lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UF83g.png)

Comment: If you do not believe that VS Code's indent guides are working properly, [please file an issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/new). Please include some sample code in the bug report so we can try to reproduce this problem and investigate it

Comment: From what I can tell from your screenshots native implementation of guides is working just differently from what Sublime authors implemented. You can try the Guides extension https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=spywhere.guides it allows for more configuration that native guides. Just remember to read the readme.